# Set layers in ggplot2 via loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would expected that

```
data <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
                   col2 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1),
                   z = rnorm(6))
p1<-ggplot(data, aes(x=col1))

for(idx in unique(data$col2)){
    p1<-p1 + geom_bar(subset = .(col2 == idx), aes(y = ..count..),fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
}
p1
```

have the same output like

```
p1<-ggplot(data, aes(x=col1))
p1<-p1 + geom_bar(subset = .(col2 == 1), aes(y = ..count..),fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
p1<-p1 + geom_bar(subset = .(col2 == 2), aes(y = ..count..),fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
p1
```

but it istn't. So how could I produce in the for loop the same output like in the second example.

Comment: What kind of plot are you looking for? Your working example does not make sense to me.

Comment: I'm thinking he can make the plot without explicitly subsetting the data

Comment: Thierry iam speaking about a principle
@Pete I know for example if I would melt the data frame by col2. But I am interrested doing this by for loop or any other loop to have the result if I would write the sequenz explicte like in the first example.

Comment: Subset the data yourself inside the loop - your loop doesn't work because `idx == 2` at the end and that's what both layers will see.

Comment: @hadley, I know but I dont understand the this behavior, because for me the code in the loop looks like I would add in each step a knew layer.

Comment: @Klaus it's complicated, because of the use of special evaluation and the fact that you're not creating a new environment in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @hadley, whereby I can compare the special evaluation? How can I store objects like `geom_bar(subset = .(col2 == 1), aes(y = ..count..),fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)` to add them later to the plot object `p1<-ggplot(data, aes(x=col1))`?

Comment: @Klaus as I said, subset the data yourself. Otherwise you'll need to http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping and http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html and the ggplot2 source code to see what's going on.

Comment: @hadley, what do you mean, if you said "subset the data yourself"? Because if use a list of subsets `split(data, data$col2)` I have no idea how to create a subset on it.

Comment: @Klaus `df <- data[data$col2 == i, ]` etc.

Comment: @hadley Okay but my question btw. I dont know how to call the geom_bar() function for each data.frame and combine the layers in one plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is simple if you do the subsetting yourself:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(
  col1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
  col2 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1),
  z = rnorm(6))
ids <- unique(data$col2)

p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(col1, y = ..count..))

for(id in ids){
  df <- data[data$col2 == id, ]
  p1 <- p1 + geom_bar(data = df, fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
}
p1
```

Comment: Many thx.  This was exactly what I tried before but it doesnt worked till now. `p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=col1))
df<-split(data, data$col2)
for(i in df){
   p1 <- p1 + geom_bar(data = i, aes(y = ..count..), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
}
p1`