# Cannot overlay multiple stat_function with ggplot2

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I have a table with a binning variable `VAR2_BY_NS_BIN` and an x-y data pair (`MP_BIN`,`CORRECT_PROP`). I want to plot the data point binned, and also draw a different line for each bin using `stat_function`, taking a different reference each time using the `for loop`.

```
test_tab <- data.table(VAR2_BY_NS_BIN=c(0.0005478, 0.0005478, 0.002266, 0.002266, 0.006783, 0.006783, 0.020709, 0.020709, 0.142961, 0.142961),
                       MP_BIN=rep(c(0.505, 0.995), 5),
                       CORRECT_PROP=c(0.5082, 0.7496, 0.5024, 0.8627, 0.4878, 0.9368, 0.4979, 0.9826, 0.4811, 0.9989))

VAR2_BIN <- sort(unique(test_tab$VAR2_BY_NS_BIN)) #get unique bin values
LEN_VAR2_BIN <- length(VAR2_BIN) #get number of bins

col_base <- c("#FF0000", "#BB0033", "#880088", "#3300BB", "#0000FF") #mark bins with different colours

p <- ggplot(data = test_tab)

for (i in 1:LEN_VAR2_BIN) {
  p <- p + geom_point(data = test_tab[test_tab$VAR2_BY_NS_BIN==VAR2_BIN[i],],
                      aes(x = MP_BIN, y = CORRECT_PROP),
                      col = col_base[i],
                      alpha = 0.5) +
           stat_function(fun = function(t) {VAR2_BIN[i]*(t-0.5)+0.5}, col = col_base[i])
}

p <- p + xlab("MP") + ylab("Observed proportion")
print(p)
```

The above code (a reproducible example), however, always returns a plot with only the last `stat_function` line drawn (which is the 5th line in the above case).

The following code (without using the `for loop`) works, but I in fact have a large number of bins so it is not very feasible...

```
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(t) {VAR2_BIN[1]*(t-0.5)+0.5}, col = col_base[1])
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(t) {VAR2_BIN[2]*(t-0.5)+0.5}, col = col_base[2])
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(t) {VAR2_BIN[3]*(t-0.5)+0.5}, col = col_base[3])
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(t) {VAR2_BIN[4]*(t-0.5)+0.5}, col = col_base[4])
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(t) {VAR2_BIN[5]*(t-0.5)+0.5}, col = col_base[5])
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a for loop or `stat_function`. To plot the points, just map `MP_BIN` and `CORRECT_PROP` to x and y and the points can be plotted with a single call to `geom_point`. For the lines, you can create the necessary values on the fly (as done in the code below) and plot those with `geom_line`.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(test_tab %>% mutate(model=VAR2_BY_NS_BIN*(MP_BIN - 0.5) + 0.5), 
       aes(x=MP_BIN, colour=factor(VAR2_BY_NS_BIN))) +
  geom_point(aes(y=CORRECT_PROP)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=model)) +
  labs(colour="VAR2_BY_NS_BIN") +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))
```

In terms of the problem you were having with the for loop, what's going on is that ggplot doesn't actually evaluate the loop variable (`i`) until you print the plot. The value of `i` is 5 at the end of the loop when the plot is printed, so that's the only line you get. You can find several questions related to this issue on Stack Overflow. [Here's one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26246791/496488).

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution works for me. May I ask also how to define my own color scheme?

Comment: `+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "green"))`. You just need to `values` to be a vector of n colors (where n=3 in this case). The default is equivalent to `+ scale_fill_manual(values=hcl(seq(15,375,length.out=4)[1:3], 100, 65))`. Also [see here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html) for other options.