# Adding layers to ggplots works but adding in a loop does not

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add to an existing ggplot in a loop. It works fine as shown in a minimal example below when I add points to a list not using a loop (left plot). When I do the same in a loop, the final result only contains the last point that I added (right plot).

```
library(ggplot2) 

p <- list(); pl <- list()
x0 <- c(-1,1); y0 <- c(-3,3); q <- c(-5,5)

#no loop
p[[1]] <- ggplot() + coord_fixed(xlim = q, ylim = q)
p[[2]] <- p[[1]] +geom_point(aes(x=x0[1], y=y0[1])) 
p[[3]] <- p[[2]] + geom_point(aes(x=x0[2], y=y0[2])) 

#loop
pl[[1]] <- ggplot() + coord_fixed(xlim = q, ylim = q)
for (i in 1:2)
{
  pl[[i+1]] <- pl[[i]] + geom_point(aes(x=x0[i], y=y0[i]))
}

p[[3]]
pl[[3]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're a victim of *lazy evaluation*.  [See, for example, [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html).]  A `for` loop uses lazy evaluation.  Fortunately, `lapply` does not.  So,

```
p <- ggplot() + coord_fixed(xlim = q, ylim = q)
lapply(
  1:2,
  function(i) p <<- p + geom_point(aes(x=x0[i], y=y0[i]))
)
```

gives you what you want.

Note the use of `<<-` as a quick and dirty fix.

Comment: Your code works for my special problem! In my search I did not find those link that you provided. "<<-" ... again something learned.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to what is called "lazy evaluation", explained in several posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235825/for-loop-only-adds-the-final-ggplot-layer)).
You don't need to add the plots into lists you just overwrite and get the same result.
As for the loop you need to put your data into a `data.frame` and feed it to the
`geom_point()` function:

```
p <- list(); pl <- list()
x0 <- c(-1,1); y0 <- c(-3,3); q <- c(-5,5)

#no loop
p <- ggplot() + coord_fixed(xlim = q, ylim = q)
p <- p +geom_point(aes(x=x0[1], y=y0[1])) 
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=x0[2], y=y0[2])) 

#loop
pl <- ggplot() + coord_fixed(xlim = q, ylim = q)
for (i in 1:2){
  data<-cbind.data.frame(x=x0[i], y=y0[i])
  pl <- pl + geom_point(data=data,aes(x=x, y=y))
}

p
pl
```

Comment: Thanks, but the other answer fits my real problem better than your answer, therefore I accpeted it - and not yours.